# Archive widget numbers translation?

Tags: translation

I've translated my theme successfully. Yet, there are some part that I couldn't find out how to translate them.

I've done [a tutorial](http://tareq.wedevs.com/2010/09/translate-wordpress-date-time-comment-number-to-bangla-digit/) to Translate or convert WordPress date/time/comment number into my local language successfully. (see the blue arrow in screenshot below)

[image: translate date and time]
<sup>*click to enlarge* ⤴</sup>

**I have some parts that need to also convert/translate such as:**

- The numbers (year) of archive widget; is it possible to convert/translate it into my local language?
- The word (on) in comment widget as well as in comment form; how could I translate it?
- The part that I rounded with red circle; how could I translate them?

Answer (score 0):

For archives you can use the get_archives_link filter like this:

```
add_filter('get_archives_link', 'translate_archive_month');
function translate_archive_month($list) {

  $patterns = array( 
    '/January/', '/February/', '/March/', '/April/', '/May/', '/June/',
    '/July/', '/August/', '/September/', '/October/',  '/November/', '/December/'
  );

  $replacements = array( //Put here whatever you want
    '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', 
    '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'
  );    

  $list = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $list);
return $list; 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's for translating the months. I want the number to convert into my local language as in the picture.

Comment: have you tried any multilanguage plugin like WPML or QTranslate? Other option would be create your own widget.

Comment: Thanks! I've used them but it doesn't have the translation of the thing that I want. I don't know how to create my own widget!